# Laravel and infinity categories as a tree

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

how to display all categories, with sub, sub, sub (..) category, I have simple table:

[image]

and my model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public $fillable = [
        'parent_id',
        'name',
        'description'
    ];

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I want to get:

```
<ul>
  <li>Category
    <ul>
      <li>Category 1.1</li>
      <li>Category 1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  (...)
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This practical approach work for ***n*** number of categories with ***n*** number of children

First create a partial view `category.blade.php` file which recursively will call itself to load its children

```
<li>
       @if ($category->children()->count() > 0 )
           <ul>
               @foreach($category->children as $category)

                       @include('category', $category) //the magic is in here

               @endforeach
           </ul>

       @endif
</li>
```

Then in the main view you add this code which loads all children recursively

```
  <ul>
        @foreach ($categories as $category)

            @if($category->parent_id == 0 )

                @include('category', $category)

            @endif
        @endforeach

    </ul>
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much! Maybe you have idea how to do this same but to select input? With indicators? eg. 
- Category
-- Category 1.1
-- Category 1.1
--- Category 1.1.1